# Is specifying the X-> Y relationship in Tensorflow Regression graph required?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a group of approximately 15 dependent variables - each a metric for a given company - which I am trying to use to predict the return on an asset. Returns are in percent form and on a continuous distribution (1%, 1.453%, 2.53% etc)

I am trying to use Tensorflow to build a Neural Network to predict the returns of the assets; however, I don't know the relationship between the Xs and the Ys.  Linear? probably not.  Polynomial?  maybe, but to what degree?

Everything I have seen in TensorFlow docs states that I need to specify the X -> Y relationship while setting up the graph.

ie. `Y = mx + b.   Or Y = ax^2 + bx + c`

If I don't know the relationship between the Xs and Ys, is there a way to use TensorFlow to solve this problem, or is it recommended to stick with RandomForest / Tree-Based models?

Comment: Welcome at SO. Maybe this question is too specialized to find someone who can answer it. It would be very appreciated that if you find a solution, you post it here as an answer to your own question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  If I do find the answer I will definitely post here!